# Grafana variables template correct but not rendering each series individually

Tags: variables, time-series, grafana, multi-select

I am trying to learn more about Grafana and have a table that has Kubernetes cluster node CPU temperatures.  I know this is available in other ways, but just wanted to create a dashboard using a single query using a variable that extracts the node names from a MySQL table and then renders each cluster node temperature series appropriately.

The variable 'Nodes' returns the correct nodes that are in the database table.  That result is something like this:

All, k3s19, k3s18, k3s17, etc....

The actual query is:

```sql
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TempTime) AS "time", CTemp
    FROM cputemperature.Temperatures
    WHERE $__timeFilter(TempTime) and ClusterNode in ( $Nodes );
```

What results is a single time series that are all the select Nodes variable results for the dashboard.  Of course selecting a single node works fine, but multi selection fails to render separate times series temperatures per node as stated.

I have also tried to format the 'Nodes' variable as `${Nodes:sqlstring}`.

I realize that I need to organize the various time series in some way but not sure how.  I made all this work by creating a Grafana query for each node, which is tedious and as I add other nodes to the cluster I have to add more queries, but wanted it to use the Nodes variable to determine the logged temperatures of nodes and use one Grafana query to render each temperature for each node series.

Thanks for the help!

```sql
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TempTime) AS "time", CTemp
    FROM cputemperature.Temperatures
    WHERE $__timeFilter(TempTime) and ClusterNode in ( $Nodes );
```

Results in a single time series of temperatures for multiple selected nodes in the 'Nodes' Variable for the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have node in the select, so that's a reason why it is only single timeserie for Grafana. Try:

```
SELECT 
  $__time(TempTime),
  ClusterNode AS "metric",
  CTemp AS "value"
FROM cputemperature.Temperatures
WHERE 
  $__timeFilter(TempTime) 
  AND ClusterNode in ($Nodes)
```

But this may select too many datapoints, so it is better to select aggregated value - it will be working better for any dashboard timerange (1 day, 1 year, ...) e.g.:

```
SELECT 
  $__timeGroup(dateColumn, $__interval),
  ClusterNode AS "metric",
  AVG(CTemp) AS "value"
FROM cputemperature.Temperatures
WHERE 
  $__timeFilter(TempTime) 
  AND ClusterNode in ($Nodes)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

See [Grafana MySQL doc](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/#macros) for used macros.

Comment: I feel like in 10 something changed regarding metric name, and there might be need for *Partition by value* transformation, but I couldn't find any documentation for it.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  The first solution works fine with any timeframes.  Thanks again!

Comment: I wanted to add a template variable of "Interval" type to easily change the timeframes via the dashboard since I will be turning off editing of items in the dashboard.  I created the variable named "timeframe" with values "1h,2h,3h,4h,5h,6h,12h,1d,2d,5d,7d". I am having trouble understanding how the first query in the above answer needs to be modified to use my "timeframe" variable?  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @techguy993, please avoid asking unrelated questions in comments.